# Did Serena Butler have living descendents?

Tags: dune, hunters-of-dune

I ask because in the first half of *[Hunters of Dune](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hunters_of_Dune)* (p204 paperback ed.) Sheeana is consulting her Other Memory and she's addressed by someone claiming to be Serena Butler. A few chapters later, this memory returns and Sheeana challenges it, pointing out Serena Butler's only child was murdered and asks how it's possible -- to which the Other Memory responds "Because I am" or "Because it is" (can't find the page ATM) before shutting up for the rest of the book.

A similar inconsistency occurs in the second half, around p415: the Baron Harkonnen ghola's memories are awakened ... but Alia is present in the Baron's mind.

Are these just continuity hiccups? Or is there some in-universe explanation?

This has bothered me for quite a while. The Herbert/Anderson books can get a little redundant but they're generally okay for continuity & consistency.

Comment: The concept of "genetic memory" in the Dune series is wildly inconsistent. Notably, Paul, Leto and Duncan Idaho all have memories that they couldn't possibly have inherited from their predecessors. There also seems to be a "psychic time & space" component that isn't explored

Comment: Is it a vision, or just really good spice...

Comment: @elliottfrisch - I haven't read the book in question for quite some time. Is there any particular reason to assume that it isn't just an hallucination, as opposed to genetic memory?

Comment: @Richard: I assumed that Anderson was snorting a little 'white spice' when he wrote those books, causing the hallucination that he was a competent author.

Comment: The easiest solution is to completely disregard anything not written by Frank Herbert.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, she never had any living descendants. Kevin J. Anderson and Brian Herbert are just really, really shitty authors. They try to cover it with a throwaway line from Erasmus about "not knowing what happened to all his clones of Serena," but those clones wouldn't have Serena's memories anyway; under *Dune* rules, they'd remember up to the point Erasmus took the skin samples, like the Duncan Idahos, but the Serena in Sheeana's Other Memory clearly remembers events that took place **after** her death. It's just really, really shitty writing. The same with your Alia example.

Comment: I agree with your assessment but not your reasoning. There has always been a substantial unexplained psychic element to dune, even in the first novels; Alia invading the Reverend mothers minds at the end of Dune or Paul seeing through Leto II"s eyes in CofD

Comment: To be fair, he was writing them based on a cocktail napkin once breathed upon by Frank Herbert and found at the back of his safe deposit box.

Comment: I don't think Herbert and Anderson are shitty writers per se, they're just, how shall I say this, not very good in imagining the world as created by Frank Herbert. In order to enjoy their books, you must first clear your mind of any concept of "canon". They write fanfiction, OK?

Comment: I quite enjoyed their books, as long as I didn't allow myself to think "No no, that's not how it really could have happened!"

Comment: @Mr Lister: Have you read anything else by Anderson? He's a verry good junior fiction writer, but that's it. *Climbing Olympus Mons* was so good I read a bunch of other stuff by him, only to discover, to my chagrin, that that book was apparently crapped out by an angel and delivered to his door, because nothing else he's done has compared to it. You are correct in calling him a fan-fiction writer; the *nuDune* books read like really, really bad fan-fiction.

Comment: @Richard: Alia was able to invade Mohiam's mind because Mohiam was her grandmother, and she was an Abomination. While this wasn't explicitly stated in the book - it was in an early draft, but Herbert dropped it for pacing - the dialogue in that scene clearly indicates that Alia is Mohiam's descendant. Leto II is Muad'Dib's son, and therefore they have a somewhat unique ability. And an "unexplained psychic element" wouldn't enable a dead woman's memories to enter the brain of a woman who bears no relation to her, thousands of years later.

Comment: @JamesSheridan Mohiam was not Alia's grandmother in canon. Frank Herbert later showed considerable chagrin at  people assuming that she was. He deliberately refrained from hinting at who the Lady Jessica's mother was in the published books.

Comment: @MrLister: I have a deleted scene, in *The Road to Dune*, that suggests otherwise. Alia's comments about "those we've been" also don't make the slightest bit of sense unless Mohiam was her ancestor.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it implies Serena had another child not revealed in other Dune books.  They could be planting a seed for some future story line to continue the series.  How and when would then require a believable basis for a second child.  Example is she had twins and one was female since Other Memories are women.  And somehow that was hidden from her.  Erasmus would do something like that.  Still, providing something plausible would be a challenge.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  The question wasn't "how might she," it was "_did_ she?"  An answer will explain how, in canon, we know she either did or did not; please don't post unsupported speculation as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a bit speculative, but in the prequel books, there were at least two Serenas:

When the war between machines and humans were slowly dying out, Serena has been sent under pretence to oversee a peace treaty. Unfortunately for her, she was just a pawn: once she has landed on the enemy territory, she has been killed by one of her bodyguards. Meanwhile, a clone of her has been tortured to death and conveniently "found" by human forces (which would obviously suggest that Machines did it), which brought a new spark to the Jihad.

So it wouldn't be hard to guess that there could be more than one clone.

Answer (score -2):

I was wondering the same thing — was it just poor continuity management, poor editing/proofing, or some sort of artistic license magic that was just glossed over… as disappointing as I think the “post-FH” Dune books have been —- which is sad to say, really; when someone pointed out it’s like fan-fiction or YA Scifi (both accurate in my opinion) in lieu of a truthful homage (in my opinion) to all things Hebertian-Dunesque —- I think at least there’s something, even if it is not the most convincing set of sequels.
One thought I had after reading the series again (D, DM, CoD, GEoD, HoD, CH, Hu’Du) was they maybe —- other than ‘Serena’ just being inserted as a deus ex machina device, heh —- was that (and maybe this explains Alia-in-Baron or Vladalia) the cells in the nullentropy capsules included all of these historic figures, and apparently were mixed in a way that they had to extract them and differentiate from Face Dancers & other Bene Tleilax cells… maybe that was it? Except, as I began to realize, while that could explain the genetic ego-ghost of Alia in the Baron, it can’t explain the Serena in Sheannah, since she isn’t a ghola. So I had to throw that idea out the window. And where Serena died to trigger a resumption of the Jihad’s fervour, it’s not like she could’ve “shared” or had her thoughts absorbed by someone with the equivalent of Bene Gesserit sharing abilities…plus she wasn’t a RM. The other thing that gets me is part of the KH concept was males with genetic memory that spanned male and female lines; if Paul and L2 had this gift, thus it tying into perfect prescience, how is it that Baron H with his maybe-caused-by-ghola-cells-mixed-up-with-Alia, has this genetic ghost but actually no other genetic memory beyond his prior life?
I dunno. Some of these plot points started to get to me. I’m not a purist or anti-creative-change but it seemed like some of it was an after thought, or “this would be cool let’s also throw this in it”, like back when frats made jungle juice with a bunch of random booze… whatever looked cool or sounded cool got dumped in, with no thought.
So, I think the ghola cell thing can maybe justify Alia in the Baron, but not the Serena in Sheannah thing.
The whole clone argument doesn’t make sense either, because the clones wouldn’t have the same genetic memory of what came after, nor does it explain some of the other things.
The other thread that makes me wonder is when FH wrote GEoD, the Tleilaxu were trying to assassinate L2; but by HoD, these Zensufis venerate him as a prophet of their faith; what and as BH & KA expand in HuDu and beyond, it is more and more confusing… there’s that line in HuDu about Uxtal or one of them thinking about the prophet before he came back as L2 that he wondered in the wasteland for some time and then brought some holy message - I think it’s between the Navigator recruiting the HM’s to force Uxtal to make melange by resurrecting Waff and the battle for Bandalong — who was that? Mohammed, Jesus,!or one of the later Buddislamic figures? How/why did they go from trying to kill L2 all the time to venerating him?
And Leto 2 (2.0) being a worm, defending himself in the crèche from Grim and the other one? He becomes a worm-baby and then nothing until later?
I dunno. I’m just lost with some of these.
While I’d still read it, I just wish that there was at least a couple good alternative sequel books that were well written and not divergent to the point where finding justifications (not trying to be a cannonist conservative purist or buzz kill) wasn’t a thing. If it had some lame explanation in the text maybe it would be a bit more tolerable - even if that wasn’t always FH’s way, since he sometimes left a lot to the imagination - and that’s all I got.

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE! This is a gigantic, unreadable wall of text at the moment. Would you mind [edit]ing this to break it up into paragraphs so it's easier to understand?

Comment: @F1Krazy - Unreadable *and* largely irrelevant.